# Low pixel density when rotation UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I have found a couple algorithm for our application to rotate annotations on MKMapView, and in every algorithm pixel density of image is crashing. Here is the example, green arrow annotation:
[image: Green arrow annotation example]

[image: Algorithm]

Maybe someone knows algorithm or extension to perform correct rotation of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with zero for the last parameter. That will maximize the screen resolution to match your device's screen (e.g. retina).

---

Even when you create the retina resolution image, when you rotate a bitmap, you're going to be introducing some further pixelation. You may get the sharper results if you draw it yourself (e.g. in the `drawRect` of the annotation view's subclass):

```
@interface CustomUserAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat angle;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lineWidth;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *strokeColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *fillColor;

@end

@implementation CustomUserAnnotationView

- (instancetype)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        self.lineWidth = 2;
        self.strokeColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);            
    }

    return self;
}

// you should probably `setNeedsDisplay` on the other properties' setters, too, but I'm assuming angle is the only one we're worried about right now.

- (void)setAngle:(CGFloat)angle {
    _angle = angle;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
    CGFloat radius = (MIN(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height) - self.lineWidth) / 2.0;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:   [self pointAtRadius:radius       percentAngle:0.0 center:center angleOffset:self.angle]];
    [path addLineToPoint:[self pointAtRadius:radius       percentAngle:0.4 center:center angleOffset:self.angle]];
    [path addLineToPoint:[self pointAtRadius:radius * 0.6 percentAngle:0.5 center:center angleOffset:self.angle]];
    [path addLineToPoint:[self pointAtRadius:radius       percentAngle:0.6 center:center angleOffset:self.angle]];
    [path closePath];
    path.lineWidth = self.lineWidth;
    path.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;

    [self.fillColor setFill];
    [path fill];

    [self.strokeColor setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}

- (CGPoint)pointAtRadius:(CGFloat)radius percentAngle:(CGFloat)percentAngle center:(CGPoint)center angleOffset:(CGFloat)angleOffset {
    CGFloat angle = M_PI * 2.0 * percentAngle + angleOffset;
    return CGPointMake(center.x + radius * sin(angle), center.y - radius * cos(angle));
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, you may still suffer some pixelation, but it won't be as bad. You can probably make it even better with a higher resolution image. Or create a `UIBezierPath` that draws this image at whatever rotation suits your needs. But if the above is good enough, then that's great.